# I have installed wsl 2 on my laptop and trying to run Jenkins jobs as a part of setup. While running the jobs, wsl image got deleted. Any idea folks?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have installed wsl 2 on my laptop and trying to run Jenkins jobs as a part of setup. WSL Image getting deleted all of a sudden while running the Jenkins jobs. I am building 5 jobs which are update distro,setup development environment, checkout all sources, pre build setup, backend build. Problem occurs during last two pipelines.

Expecting to run the Jenkins jobs successfully and bring up front end service through wsl.

Comment: are you using wsl commands or managing the folders related with wsl?